# How to use sync eloquent method

Tags: laravel

Hello i am trying to make a code that updates existing values by removing existing ones/add new ones or make changes in the existing values. This is the code i have done so far:

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $order = Order::find($id);

        $request->validate([
            'order_number' => 'required',
            'client_id' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'productOrder' => 'required',
            'productOrder.*.product_id' => 'required|distinct|exists:products,id',
            'productOrder.*.amount' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
        ]);

        $order->update($request->all());

        foreach ($request->productOrder as $product) {

            $values[] = [
                'order_id' => $order->id,
                'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                'amount' => $product['amount'],
            ];

            $amount = Product::find($product['product_id']);

            $totalValue = $product['amount'] + $amount->amount;

            $amount->update(['amount' => $totalValue]);

//            $order->products()->sync([$product['product_id'] => array(
//                'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
//                'amount' => $product['amount'],  THIS CODE MAKES ERROR BY DELETING ALL THE VALUES EXCEPT ONE
//            )]);
        }

        $order->products()->detach();
        $order->products()->attach($values); //I WANT THE CODE TO DO THIS FUNCTIONS BASICALLY

        $orders = Order::all();

        $orders->load('client', 'products');

        return view('orders/index', compact('orders'));
    }
```

Comment: If I have understood you.: Do you want to update a pivot table?

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezDíaz yes

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezDíaz but when i use `$order->products()->sync($values);` the values get updated but if i have existing `[1,2]` and i add `[1,2,3]` the values will be saved as `[2,3]`

Comment: I have been reading about `sync`method. I think the record with ID 1 is been deleting because it's not specified in the array you're passing

Comment: the array i pass it has it has that ID because if i do `dd($values);` it shows it

Comment: `array:2 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php:106
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "order_id" => 245
    "product_id" => "7"
    "amount" => "20"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "order_id" => 245
    "product_id" => "3"
    "amount" => "50"
  ]
]`   This is the result it shows now with the `sync` code the first value will be deleted and just the second one will be left its like either replacing it or delete it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this

```
$values = [];
foreach ($request->productOrder as $product) {
    /* This is the sync id     &&       This is the pivot column */
    $values[$product['product_id']] = ['amount' => $product['amount']];
    $amount = Product::find($product['product_id']);
    $totalValue = $product['amount'] + $amount->amount;
    $amount->update(['amount' => $totalValue]);

}

// $values keys must be a product_id and its value must be pivot values

$order->products()->sync($values);
```